# PHP mysqli_query returning 0 unless I limit number of query results

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm currently running a query in PHP using mysqli_query (using an Amazon EC2 instance on the free tier) I am json_encoding the results and returning them. For some reason, if I don't place a limit on the number of query results to return (or set the limit to something above 158 results), the array returns '0'. However, if I do place a limit <= 158 results, all of my results return correctly in an array. Code below:

```
function pullFriendData() {
    $userID = $GLOBALS['userID'];
    $userArray = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `userID` in (SELECT `friendID` FROM `UserFriends` WHERE `userID` = '" . $userID . "'";
    if ($query_result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], $query)) {
        while ($row = $query_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $row = convertUserToInt($row);
            array_push($userArray, cleanse($row));
        }
    } else {
        echo "[pullFriendData]: Issue with finding friends of given user";
    }
    return json_encode($userArray);
}
```

Very strange behavior - has anybody come across this? Is this a PHP issue or is it perhaps an EC2 issue? It should also be noted that I run several other queries on various tables which return hundreds and hundreds of results with no issue.

Comment: Pleas don't use `$GLOBALS` and you are better of using a join on this query

Comment: php couldn't care less how many/few records the query resturns, unless you're returning big blobs and filling up memory.

Comment: Change your query to something like this:
"SELECT * FROM `User` 
                        JOIN `UserFriends`
                                ON `User`.`id` = `UserFriend`.`userID`
                        WHERE `UserFriend`.`userID` = '$userID'"

And see what that gives you

Comment: @SuperDJ I started off using a JOIN query and the same issue was happening, which was why I tried using a subquery

Comment: What do you mean by "the array returns 0"?  What array? Where are you getting a value of 0? Is this an encoding problem (i.e. something in your table at line 159 is not able to be encoded) or a data retrieval problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because json_encode breaks on accented characters, and one of my query results (at position 160 exactly) happened to include an accented character